# SBS 2011, Server Performance plunged after activating administrator account

Tags: performance, windows-sbs-2011

After activating the built in "administrator account" on a SBS 2011 server, the performance of the server went down to almost un-usable in the GUI. Can log on as another user, but performance is severely affected. Click on start and it takes 2 minutes to display the start menu.

If I disable the built in administrator account, will that help? Server resources are looking normal (Ram usage, Disk Usage, CPU usage etc) RAID is running optimal. SQL Server is reporting an IO error on a database, but to my knowledge the customer is not using SQL server.

Any tips will be greatly appreciated, very stressed out at the moment!

Answer (score 0):

Found SQL server for some unknown reason at this time was bogging it down. Stop the SQL agents and it all comes to life.